# How do I get the appcmd? Windows 10

Tags: command, windows-10, appcmd

How do I get the appcmd to write commands? Using Windows 10. Getting this error:

*'appcmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.*

Also, if I have used this command:

*appcmd delete site "Default Web Site"*

If I what to do the opposite - do I use *add* instead of *delete*?

Answer (score 13):

`Appcmd.exe` is located at path `%windir%\system32\inetsrv` and by default is not listed in `PATH` variable. So in order to use this command you have to navigate to this folder first and then you can update IIS configuration using `appcmd` utility.

By the way `appcmd.exe` is available only to the Administrator account or to users who are members of the Administrators group on the computer.

And to your second question, yes opposite verb to `DELETE` is `ADD`.

More information can be found at documentation: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635852(v=ws.11).aspx#BKMK_Start